# Reporting with InfluxDB

Tags: linux, pdf, database, reporting, nosql

We use the time series database InfluxDB for recording environmental values (temperature, humidity, ...). The data volume is growing fast.

We are looking for a reporting tool that

- builds metrics (average temp per minute, per day, per month...)
- generates reports in pdf format
- saves these reports in a samba share or ftp server on a daily, weekly, monthly base
- runs on Linux

In the best case, it also helps configuring reports in pdf format with a web user interface.

So far we have only seen great reporting tools for SQL databases (as JasperReports, ...). But how to report from InfluxDB without writing software on our own?

Answer (score 1):

**[Grafana](https://grafana.com/)** works with **InfluxDB** by default.

**[Grafana reporter](https://github.com/IzakMarais/reporter)** can generate reports from the Dashbords.

Now you can simply use **cron** with **curl**/**wget** to download the files and place them at the desired location.

---

Your reluctance to write own software is understandable, however libraries like **[Python Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)** or **matplotlib** could be used to write a high level script generating such reports with *relative* ease.